# Datalist contain Image control how to bind imageurl dynamically through code

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind folder containing images..this folder get dynamically created.then how to bind this folder path to image url?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how you're dynamic path etc looks like but you can try something like this

Codebehind

```
string dynamicPath = "~/dynamicimages/";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath( dynamicPath));
        FileInfo[] dirInfos = dir.GetFiles();

        Repeater1.DataSource = dirInfos;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected string GetImageURL(object fileName)
    {
        return dynamicPath + fileName.ToString();
    }
```

The .aspx file

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImageURL(Eval("Name")) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```